# How to apply a animation to an imageview in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

what i am trying to do here is,i have downloaded some images in my application and i want to show these images one by one to the user in full screen after some times say every 30 seconds.I also applied an animation to the imageview when image changes here is my code:-

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!isCancelled()) 
    {

    filename=params[0];
   if(ShowImages.vn>d2)
   {
    ShowImages.vn=0;   
   }
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
    }
    return bmp;

}
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ShowImages.tt1.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
         r1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ShowImages.context, R.anim.lefttoright);
        ShowImages.tt1.setImageBitmap(result);
        ShowImages.tt1.startAnimation(r1);
    }

    }
```

this is my code for my animation file:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
           android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
            android:duration="700"/>
       </set>
```

i have no problem with this code it is executing fine,but when the image change takes place the whole imageview goes blank for some time and then the next image comes.I do not want this,i want the previous image to be there untill the next image change has taken place,can someone suggest me a method for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be good to use [frame-by-frame animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) as well define on developer site *Frame- by- frame:  An object used to create frame-by-frame animations, defined by a series of Drawable objects, which can be used as a View object's background.*

Check below tutorial even you will get more example, just try to Google:

[Displaying a frame-by-frame animation in Android](http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=813)